# DataTables individual column search

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to implement individual column searh, but it seems to not be working.

When i have the fields under eah column which have been created accordinly to the documentation.

```
        $('.table tfoot th').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" name="'+title+'" />' );
        });
```

It will create 3 different fields, for each of my columns, when i type anything on them, a request is triggered to my server, everything is fine.

I was looking into the request header and found out that all `sSearch_#` were filled, as you can see on the image below.

[image]

As you can see, when i typed on the first field (first column) it triggered `sSearch_0`, `sSearch_1` and `sSearch_2`. It should have triggered just `sSearch_0` because i typed on the first column.

I have no idea how to fix this.

**updating**

```
<table class="permissions table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Group/User</th>
        <th>Permission</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Path</th>
            <th>Group/User</th>
            <th>Permission</th>
          </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Comment: Hi! If I get you right, you use serverSide option? You only want to send your filter options to the server side? Could you add your table html code please?

Comment: @Igorovics yes, i do use server side and i want to send some filter options to the server side. I'm updating the code.

Comment: I thought the problem was that all the search parameters were sent by the same name, but I was wrong. What happens if you try to read the search parameter manually at server side? For example $POST["Permission"] in PHP, or as a @Requestparam in Spring, etc. Can you get the values like that?

Comment: Another question: do you use the default filtering, or custom filtering?